# Difference between getting value by dictionary key multiple times instead of linking the value in PyPy

Tags: python, pypy

For instance I have a code.

```
def my_function(my_dict, selections_list): 
    for value in selections:
        if value in my_dict:  #  maybe try -> except KeyError ?!
            a = my_dict[value] 
            # Do something
            if my_dict[value]:
                ....
            # use my_dict[value] multiple times as right value.
            # ....
            # Very complicated code
```

Is there any major reason to link my_dict[value] and use the linked object  in pypy if my_function will be called million times.

```
def my_function(my_dict, selections_list): 
    for value in selections:
        if value in my_dict:  #  maybe try -> except KeyError ?!
            a = my_dict[value] 
            # Do something
            if a:
            # use a multiple times instead if my_dict[value]
            # ....
            # Very complicated code
```

I want to understand whether PyPy is so smart or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to run both ways 100 000 times and timed it. As a result: no major difference. I guess PyPy is not that smart.